# Get object's serial number based on depth in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of deeply nested objects

```
     [
         {
          id: 1,
          name: "task 1",
          wbs: 1
          children: [
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "task 1.1",
              wbs: 1.1
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "task 2",
          wbs: 2
          children: [
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "task 2.1",
              wbs: 2.1
              children: [
                {
                  id: 2,
                  name: "task 2.1.1",
                  wbs: 2.1.1
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "task 3",
          wbs: 3
          children: []
        },
    ]
```

The wbs number should be generated according to the position and depth the object is at. How can I generate this number when I push a new object to the array.

That is, if I push a new object to the children array of task 1, the wbs number should be 1.2. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is your expected output look like?

Comment: I want to know what the newly added object's wbs number would be. ie, If I'm adding a new object adjascent to task 2.1.1, I need to get the wbs number as 2.1.2.

Comment: give us an example... provide your expected output in your question

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays keep a reliable insertion order, we can do this rather easily actually! We can even create a simple prototype function to streamline this process if you're doing this often in your project:

```js
let obj = [
  { id: 1, name: "task 1", wbs: "1", children: [ { id: 2, name: "task 1.1", wbs: "1.1", children: [] } ] },
  { id: 1, name: "task 2", wbs: "2", children: [ { id: 2, name: "task 2.1", wbs: "2.1", children: [ { id: 2, name: "task 2.1.1", wbs: "2.1.1", children: [] } ] } ] },
  { id: 1, name: "task 3", wbs: "3", children: [] }
];

Array.prototype.wbsPush = function() {
  const array = this;
  if (!array.every(el => el.wbs)) return false;
  const previousWbs = array[array.length - 1].wbs;
  const newWbs = previousWbs.split('.').reverse().map((e,i) => i ? e : parseInt(e) + 1).reverse().join('.');
  array.push({ id: array[array.length - 1].id + 1, name: `task ${newWbs}`, wbs: newWbs, children: [] });
}

obj.wbsPush(); // -> wbs: 4
obj[0].children.wbsPush(); // -> wbs: 1.2

console.log(obj);
```